# Почему не выполняется условие? И как можно подправить?

Tags: java, android

Почему не выполняется условие в java коде? Вот код

```
String temps=server.getOnliOff(position);

if(temps!="off"){

    SharedPreferences mServer = getSharedPreferences("mServer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mServer.edit();
    editor.putString("mServer", server.getName(position));
    editor.apply();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Autorizes.class);
    startActivity(intent);


    finish();

} else toster("Сервер не доступен");

toster("'"+temps+"'");
```

Сделал я специально функцию `toster("'"+temps+"'");` чтобы увидеть что там и вот что в перменной [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне надо чтобы выполнилось toster("Сервер не доступен"); если  в переменной off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кто то не знает про сравнение объектов? Поясню в java, каждая строка в том числе объявленная анонимно представляет собой объект. При использовании сравнения != объекты сравниваются по ссылке, а не по значению. Для сравнения по значению нужно использовать метод equals или его отрицание в этом случае.

```
!("off".equals(temps))
```

Comment: сейчас набегут специалисты по жава и скажут, что лучше писать сравнение так `"off".equals(temps)`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное все работает!

Comment: @KoVadim Почему лучше писать "off".equals(temps)?

Comment: Потому что temps может быть теоретически равным null. Проработайте оба варианта кода в этом случае.

Comment: @KoVadim Действительно. Спасибо за ответ.